# Xamarin.Forms Shell combine and order FlyoutItem with MenuItem in hambuger menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I currently have a FlyoutItem with the FlyoutDisplayOptions property in AsMultipleItems, what this does is that the hamburger menu contains as elements the same secondary elements as the tabbed page. I also have some MenuItems in my design, at this moment it does not allow me to place a MenuItem inside the FlyoutItem, this is my current design:

- FlyoutItem 1
- FlyoutItem 2
- FlyoutItem 3
- FlyoutItem 4
- FlyoutItem 5
- MenuItem 1
- MenuItem 2
- MenuItem 3
- MenuItem 4
- MenuItem 5

[image]

For example, I want MenuItem 1 to be under FlyoutItem 1 and I can't do it in any way, does anyone know how I can sort an item that is not inside the FlyoutItem within that structure? For example, I would like this design:

- FlyoutItem 1
- MenuItem 1
- FlyoutItem 2
- MenuItem 2
- FlyoutItem 3
- MenuItem 3
- FlyoutItem 4
- MenuItem 4
- FlyoutItem 5
- MenuItem 5

Currently I can only order one structure over another, but I cannot combine and order different structures from each other.

This is my code:

```
  <FlyoutItem Route="home" x:Name="flyoutItem"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab1" Title="FlyoutItem 1"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab2" Title="FlyoutItem 2"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab3" Title="FlyoutItem 3"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab4" Title="FlyoutItem 4"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab5" Title="FlyoutItem 5"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 3"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 4"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 5"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multi `FlyoutItem` like the following code .

```
<FlyoutItem Route="home" x:Name="flyoutItem"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab1" Title="FlyoutItem 1"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:x}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<FlyoutItem Route="home" 
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab2" Title="FlyoutItem 2"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"
          IconImageSource="home_icon" />

<FlyoutItem Route="home" 
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab3" Title="FlyoutItem 3"
                  Style="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                  Icon="home_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate DataTemplate views:x}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem 3"
          IconImageSource="home_icon"/>
```

Comment: I tried this too, but by doing this you lose the tabbedPage, it would not help me for this case, since I want to keep the tabbedPage.

Comment: Actually , Xamarin suggests that we set the `FlyoutItem` and  `MenuItem` as what you have done .MenuItem 1 to be under FlyoutItem 1 is not a wise way .

Comment: But the way Xamarin currently proposes assumes that the hamburger menu has to show the same order in its elements as the page with tabs and that's wrong, the UX team can tell you that you want a design with the page with tabs and A hamburguer menu, but they should not necessarily share the order of items. I will open a suggestion on the official GitHub to address this in the future.

Comment: OK, we will focus on it .